# How does one, if it is possible, destroy a death note?

Tags: death-note

I know that the death notes have certain, almost magical, attributes to them (unlimited pages, the fact that you can kill someone by envisioning their face and writing their name down, etc). Given that, I was wondering if these properties apply to their destructibility too and if that was the case, whether Light's plan to burn the Death Note if someone opened his desk incorrectly would even have worked in the first place.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to destroy a death note. It is quite unlikely as it is no ordinary book.

Comment: I was wondering why this question got downvote, it seems like good question to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember in [Episode 2 - Confrontation](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Confrontation), Light and Ryuk are in a secluded area where Light explains to Ryuk how he will devise a way to prevent others from touching the death note, pouring flammable liquid on a book and lighting it on fire.

The purpose of the experiment was for creating a trap for the Death Note because Ryuk warns Light that if Saya were to touch the Death Note when she came in to get help on her homework, she would be able to see him. this blows Lights original plan to claim to have been taking notes as practice for becoming a detective should someone discover the death note.

Later in the Episode light is explaining to Ryuk back in his room about how he has hidden the Death Note, i can't be for sure what light says but he does say the explosion from his booby trap will "destroy the evidence" so he may be hinting that the Death Note would be destroyed aswell.

In the [Rules](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note) it makes references to the Death Note being destroyed, in How to use LXII, it says

> If the victim’s name has been written and then the Death Note is destroyed in the middle of writing the cause of death, the victim will be killed by heart attack in 40 seconds after writing the name.

Finally the second live action film of Death Note "The Last Name" however, when Rem dies from killing Watabi, to prevent Light getting his hands on another Death Note Rem destroys it aswell, however since the live action movies play out differently to the anime i'm not sure how close they are to the canon on how the Death Note works.

With all of this, it seems like the death note can be destroyed, however i'm unsure if How to Use: XXXI is still in effect if a page is ripped out before the note is destroyed, it is after Light creates this booby trap he starts to rip out pages and use them instead like when he was being watched

Comment: Out of curiosity, where was this in the series?

Comment: @hungerartist Light using the bucket? not sure exactly, it's been a while but it would be before Light explaining about the false bottom to his draw and the "key" to it

Comment: yeah, I'm referring to the bucket - I remember the false bottom bit, but I don't remember seeing Light trying to light (unintentional pun I guess?) the notebook on fire, at least not in the anime.

Comment: @hungerartist i looked up the episode, it was episode 2 but it might not have been the death note that was put in the bucket, when i first saw it i though Light was making it fire resistant but i may have been mistaken, i've reviewed my answer based off a better investigation using the wiki rather than just relying on my shoddy memory

Comment: @Memor-X I looked it up in the manga and in chapter 4, page 16 it shows light's plan to light the book on fire and on the rules page you posted for How to Use: LXII it says that "Once the victim’s name, cause of death and situation of death have been written down in the Death Note, this death will still take place even if that Death Note or the part of the note in which it has been written is destroyed, for example, burned into ashes, before the stated time of death." So I would presume that since it was stated as an option to burn the Death Note to ashes that Light's plan would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

In ep35 of the anime, it is clearly shown that a paper from the Death Note held by Takada is burned in the flames when she and her body got burned by Light actions earlier. and every page of the Death Note is known to have the powers of the Death Note.
[image]